# HTML input box without a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to have an `input` box in a `div` without a form and when the user enters something and hits return, it should run a Javascript function.

There will be no submit button.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 23):

To get an input box without a form, I would suggest just not using a form.

Comment: No, input without form is perfectly valid [X]HTML.

Comment: chibineku: in addition to what bobince said: the HTML 4.01 standard specifies that "The elements used to create controls [e.g. input elements] generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces. " (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls)

Comment: Should be noted that IE8 does not modify the DOM when you click `input` elements that appear outside of a form. So whatever you do with a checkbox, it doesn't change unless it's within `<form>`.

Comment: Eventually the question becomes "Do you want this webpage to work without javascript?" Even in that case you can still associate external input elements to a form on the page, using the form parameter <input form="myForm">. More info: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp In any case, traditionally, and code-purity-wise, it's expected that input elements should be actual child elements in a form.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to attach a onkeypress event and check if enter was pressed (and rune the code if it was). Tell us if you are using plain JavaScript or some library if you need examples.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply done with the help of a form as follow... i think adding form would provide great stability

```
<form onSubmit='alerttest(this); return false'>        
    <input type="text">         
</form>


<script language="javascript">
    function alerttest() {
        alert("Executing jolly.exe !!!!");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a function when the user presses enter when focused on the input field, the easiest way would be to have the form tag and run the function using the form's `onSubmit` event (because pressing return when focused on an input field submits the form).

If you nevertheless don't want to include the form tag, you can use the `onKeyPress` event to catch the return key pressing and call the function from there.

Comment: In this case keypress is more appropriate. If one wants to catch non-character keys, keyup or keydown events should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the form tag. You can easily use JQuery to tie the code to the input control's key press events.

If you are unfamiliar with JQuery, just tie the code directly to the input field key press event.